# How to handle multiple different format xml payloads in the node js api

Tags: arrays, node.js, xml, rest, api

I have to accept different types of xml formats in the node api, based on the value that is defined need to perform respective operations.

Here is the code which I'm trying:

```
var xmlparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');
    app.post('/xmlparser',xmlparser({trim: false, explicitArray: false}),function(request,reply){
    var data = JSON.stringify(request.body);
    var arr_data =JSON.parse(data);
    //code to access and display values from the xml

    console.log("xml 1:"+arr_data['ps0:tfg']['ps0:header']['ps1:messageid']);
    console.log("xml 2:"+arr_data['ps1:hls']['ps1:header']['ps1:messageid']);
})
```

Here are the 2 different xml, that takes as an input.

```
xml 1:
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ps0:TFG xmlns:ns0="http://www.google.com/LOGO/Common">
    <ps0:Header version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://www.google.com/LOGO/Common">
    <ps1:MessageId>MESSAGE001</ns1:MessageId>
    </ps0:Header>
    </ns0:TFG>

xml 2:    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ps0:HLS xmlns:ns0="http://www.google.com/LOGO/Common">
    <ps0:Header version="1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://www.google.com/LOGO/Common">
    <ps1:MessageId>MESSAGE001</ns1:MessageId>
    </ps0:Header>
    </ps0:HLS>
```

I'm accepting different formats with in the same code as mentioned above, if i pass xml 1, xml 1 printing fine.
if i pass the xml 2 as input, execution stops at 1st console log as the index is not available.

How can we handle this condition?

To resolve this I need to keep some conditions, atleast if it is showing undefined then i can mark in the condition, problem code is not executing if index mismatches.

**Update: I have tried implementing try catch as well, but still no luck.**

Comment: First, your XML documents don't seem to be well-formed - your opening & closing tags don't match (`<ps1:MessageId>...</ns1:MessageId>` and other mismatches). Second, what are you using to parse the XML? `JSON.parse` is for parsing JSON; it will throw an exception if you try to parse XML.

Comment: i have created a sample xml to post this question, when creating i missed to close message id, modified

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably stems from the fact that both XML and Javascript/JSON are case-sensitive.

For example,

```
const c = { alpha: 42 };
console.log(c.alpha) // ---> 42
console.log(c.Alpha) // ---> undefined
```

Likewise, in XML `<ns1:MESSAGEID>` is not the same tag as `<ns1:MessageId>`.

It is possible that whatever package you're using to parse your XML is messing around with the case, but that seems highly unlikely to me - any package that does that would not be compliant with standards.

Comment: after converting, all the letters are converted to small in the result. so accessing with lower case and fyi values are displaying correctly if the index matches. Not display or not showing any error if the indexes are not matching.

Comment: how are you parsing the XML?

Comment: I assume you're using the express XML body parser package? Please make sure you provide enough information in the question for people to help you without making them work to figure out your environment. It appears that this library does, in fact, change the case of XML tags - which seems like a bad idea to me. You might try playing with the settings for that package.

Comment: Im using var xmlparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');

Comment: any idea on this?